# What is the importance of DTD and how it affects the display of the web page page

Tags: asp.net, html, xml, xhtml, dtd

What is the importance of DTD and how it affects the display of the web page page at runtime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, this tells the browser what exact type of document (eg. HTML version) you are targeting. In particular some browsers have a "quirks mode" and a "strict mode" which both render (display) your HTML differently at runtime.

There is a somewhat useful [DOCTYPE article on A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/doctype/) to help you choose the right DTD.

Answer (score 0):

DTD defines the type of document and in particular the specific version of the HTML spec you intended to target.